# Binding between Java Objects and Records

Tags: java, nosql, orientdb

I have an embedded document based OrientDB database with records and I can't read back the saved entities. A get the right number of elements, but the attributes aren't mapped to my pojo's fields.
What am I doing wrong? Any tips?

Thanks!

```
        OObjectDatabaseTx db = new OObjectDatabaseTx("local:db");
        if (db.exists()) {
            db = new OObjectDatabaseTx("local:db").open("admin", "admin");
        } else {
            db.create();
        }

        db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(User.class);

        long cnt = db.countClass(User.class);
        System.out.println(cnt); // OK

        User user = db.newInstance(User.class, "Firstname", "Lastname", "email@example.com");

        db.begin();
        db.save(user); // it's OK, the DB contains this document, I can select it with the servers console
        db.commit();

        for (User usr : db.browseClass(User.class)) {
            System.out.println(usr); // User object with null fields, why?
        }
```

The User class:

```
public class User {

private String firstname;

private String lastname;

private String email;

public User() {
}

public User(String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstname + " " + lastname + " " + email;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java objects retrieved directly from OrientDB (as you're doing in this example) are *proxied* transparently to their underlying records, allowing lazy loading of their fields. In your scenario, you'll have to use the `User` object `get` methods in order to trigger the population of the corresponding fields from the DB. The fields have default values (all `null` in your case) until loaded.

See also: "How It Works" in [OrientDB Object2RecordJavaBinding](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Object-2-Record-Java-Binding)

Answer (score 0):

As referenced in the Binding section of the Orientdb docs, you must provide an empty constructor for each java object you wish to bind. Source : http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Object-2-Record-Java-Binding.html